# Why do I get a 401 using a Shared Access Signature with the Service Bus REST API

Tags: c#, azure, rest, azureservicebus, shared-access-signatures

I'm trying to verify that I can hand-roll a SAS using the an Azure Shared Access Policy Primary Key and post to a Service Bus topic. But I always get a 401. Searching around, the below code looks correct and common place to achieve this. Have I missed something fundamental? Am I using the wrong key (i.e. Shared Access Policy Primary Key from the portal admin)? (note I'm intentionally using RootManageSharedAccessKey to test this out)

```
            var baseUrl = "https://<< NAMESPACE >>.servicebus.windows.net/";
            var key = "<< SHARED ACCESS KEY >>";

            TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
            var expiry = Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + week);
            string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseUrl) + "\n" + expiry;
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
            var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseUrl), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, "RootManageSharedAccessKey");
            var msg = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(baseUrl + "things"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post
            };
            msg.Content = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            msg.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"SharedAccessSignature sr={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseUrl)}&sig={sasToken}&se={expiry}&skn=things");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var r = client.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine(r.StatusCode);
```

Comment: Please try by changing your baseUrl to `https://<< NAMESPACE >>.servicebus.windows.net/things`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried that one but a number of examples show a base URL which excluded either the topic name, or the "messages" part where a queue name was specified. Including "things" in the url still returns unauthorized

Comment: The root shared access key has permissions to the entire namespace, including any child entities - so the namespace level URI should be fine.

Comment: Any chance that you can add a sample of what your header looks like with the actual SAS redacted?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that you're seeing the failure because of the trailing slash in your `baseUrl`.  The form is expected as: `<< NAMESPACE >>.servicebus.windows.net` and I don't believe that it is treated as a normalized URL when validated by the service - so the slash is meaningful.  *([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue#request-headers))*

The formatting of your signature looks correct, and seems to be using the snippet from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#c) almost verbatim.  For your actual application use, I'd recommend disposing the `HMACSHA256` instance and ensuring that you treat the `HttpClient` as a singleton.

In case it helps, the source for how the Service Bus SDK forms the SAS can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Authorization/SharedAccessSignature.cs#L342).

Comment: Good call on the actual source code! Totally forgot I could look that up. I can see that I'm creating the signature correctly, and even if I copy the source for building a signature, I still get 401, so must be doing something pretty fundamentally wrong. Even with backslash removed.
The actual token I get is different though - which I'll look at - but if the header created by BuildSignature isn't working....

Comment: UDPATE: Difference in signature after hashing is WebUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode do not produce the same string (different casings), but for eventual comparison that will make no difference, so the difference in token isn't the issue.

Comment: I was focused on the signature generation earlier, but looking at the header formation, you've got `skn=thing` - which is your topic.   That parameter is looking for the name of the shared key.   Also, be sure to double-check your request URI.   With the slash gone, if you didn't adjust how you're forming the URL, it would be malformed.

Comment: Sorry, should have confirmed I added "/things" to the Uri being requested. Also confusingly I was using a KeyName with the same name as the entity... but you're correct I switched to using RootManageSharedAccessKey and didn't update the auth header. 
The new header generated by the copied BuildSignature has the correct skn, but it's still returning 401. 
In the following I note they say:
The resource URI is the full URI of the Service Bus resource 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas

Comment: An HTTP 401 would typically indicate "we don't know who you are" rather than "we know who you are and you don't have permission to do this."    That makes me think we're still having issues with the header.   (though the older Azure APIs are not great at following REST conventions...)    An example may help.

Comment: OK! (or rather Created) - good news. The time offset in my BuildSignature call was wrong. I then received a BadRequest and found that the "/message" url part needs to be on the end of the entity (i.e. things/messages). By self built signature is still failing, but at least I can now find out why! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad that you're at least closer;  I forgot the that Service Bus SDK also talks to the old ATOM API via HTTP - which should act similarly to the endpoints that you're working with.   The code for forming those requests can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Administration/HttpRequestAndResponse.cs#L264), just in case you wanted to reference.

Comment: Final update - wow, it's always something silly in the end, though this was not the origina issue. When I changed the HTTP encoding to use WebUtility instead of HttpUtility, on my own sig creation I encoded the string to sign using WebUtility but had left the encoding of the request url (sr param) to HttpUtility. So there was a mismatch, e.g %a vs %A on encodings... expected in to convert to a common case when comparing after unhashing

Comment: Wow, that's subtle and frustrating.   Glad that you got it sorted out.  I'll definitely remember that for the future...